# how maven jboss-as-maven-plugin know the jboss location at runtime?

Tags: maven, plugins, deployment

i have configired jboss maven plugin as below and it is working fine.

My question is how maven know the jboss deployments location at runtime,as maven is deploying the application in the Jboss server?I have not configured the jboss deployments location,then how is it done?

The configuration of plugin is as follows...

```
<build>
    <finalName>Demo1</finalName>
    <defaultGoal>clean install jboss-as:redeploy</defaultGoal>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                        <username>rchappidi</username>
                        <password>password</password>
                        <force>true</force>
                        <port>9999</port>
                        <name>Demo1.war</name>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this configuration works and does what you want to do?

Reading the plugin documentation, it looks like you have to set the [`targetDir`](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/redeploy-mojo.html#targetDir) to the target directory where you want your application to be deployed. Quoting the documentation,

> **targetDir**: The target directory the application to be deployed is
>   located.
>
> ```
> Type: java.io.File
> Required: No
> User Property: jboss-as.deployment.targetDir
> Default: ${project.build.directory}/
> ```

Comment: yeah ,it works fine. i am able to deploy the war . it runs successfully.is there any chance of deploying an application depending on the port(may be stupip one)

Comment: @ravinderreddy did you check the effective POM to see if the config includes this `targetDir` setting somehow? Are you using `Maven Profiles` in addition to this `<build>` configuration?

Comment: no. i am not using any profiles i just configured this plugin in my  pom.i have tried without including the dependencies and no parent tag too.and also i dont have  any of the property related to jboss in classpath